# How to navigate on specific page in Xamarin Forms iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using `Xamarin Forms` and working with `ANH` notification. I am able to receive Notification from ANH. But the problem is when I am receiving notification and try to open it from notification area I want to redirect on a specific page of notification in iOS. I have used `PendingIntent` on Android, But for iOS I have no idea.

Also, I want to display a badge on the tab when an app is open and received notification. I am using `CustomRenderer` for iOS. My code is for TabRenderer is :

```cs
public class BottomTabbedPage : TabbedRenderer
{       
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        TabBar.UnselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(208,208,208);
        TabBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        TabBar.Items[1].BadgeValue = SettingClass.MenuNotificationCount == 0 ? null : SettingClass.MenuNotificationCount.ToString();
        TabBar.Items[2].BadgeValue = SettingClass.PromoNotificationCount == 0 ? null  : SettingClass.PromoNotificationCount.ToString();
    }
}
```

While App is starting badges will be displayed but when App is in background and notification is received count is increased but when the app is started badges are not updating. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

- To navigate to a specific page you can use the below code in AppDelegate.cs when you receive or process the notification.

await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new specificPage());

- To update the badge count when the app is open you need to capture the badge count when the notification is received and update it accordingly.

Comment: But in iOS how can we identify app is opened from Notification?

Comment: When the app is open the below method will be called.
public override void OnActivated(UIApplication uiApplication).

Comment: Okay, Thanks I will check and try it.